# SwitchMap from one outer observable to multiple innser observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a method which makes a http request to delete all records and then makes another http request to add a new record, for each record in the records array (I am not expecting the below code to work, it's just to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve):

```
addNewRecords(recordToDelete: Record, recordsToAdd: Record[]) {
    this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/delete`, recordToDelete).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        recordsToAdd.forEach(record => {
          this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/add`, record);
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

I want to use RXJS to subscribe the outer observable, then call the inner observables concurrently.

Is there a way this can be achieved with RXJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code the inner(post) requests will be made parallel but after delete request:

```
addNewRecords(recordToDelete: Record, recordsToAdd: Record[]=[]) {
    this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/delete`, recordToDelete).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        if(recordsToAdd.length === 0) return of([])
        const newRecords$ = recordsToAdd.map(record => {
          return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/add`, record);
        });
        return forkJoin(newRecords$)
      })
    );
  }
```

Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Having said that, I actually wanted the mapped observables to run concurrently rather than one by one. My mistake. Perhaps I should use mergemap...